# Google Drive API with service account for Google workspace account

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

Using service account credentials of the GCP project I want to access the Google 'My drive' of the Google workspace account without pre-authorising the folder.

I am successfully able to authorize and access the folder that have been shared with the service account but I want to access the 'My Drive' of all the GWS account in the same Domain.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to grant a service account access to someone's google drive account.

The first and easiest is to simply share a folder with the Service account.   This will act just like it would if you shared the folder with anyone else.  They would get access to it.   The draw back to this method is that you can only share a folder.  You cant for example share a root folder the of the users Google drive account.

In the case of google workspace there is a second option.

THe admin of the Google workspace domain can set up something called [domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) for the service account.  By setting up domain wide delegation you are giving the service account the ability to impersonate or pretend to be the actual user of that account.

So in the case of the code below.  The service object is created and we tell it which user we are going to impersonate this being gsuiteUser.

```
 var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\creds.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

 var gsuiteUser = "xxx@YourDomain.com";

 var service = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccount)
        {
            User = gsuiteUser,
            Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend, GmailService.Scope.GmailLabels }

        }.FromCertificate(certificate);
```

So as far as google drive api is concerned all requests that come from my service object are coming from gsuiteUser which means that i can see everything that this  user can see including the root directory.

You should set up domain wide delegation and have your code impersonate each of the users on your domain.  Or create a separate user with access to everything and let the service account access that single user.

Comment: How a service account be able to access that single user's "My Drive" if it cannot access the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is actually possible.

You need to:

1. Create the project/service account/get the service account credentials (.json key)
2. Enable [Domain Wide Delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106) in the Google Workspace Admin console by adding the client ID + the scopes required.
3. In your code, you need to make sure to impersonate the accounts (in your Google Workspace domain), you want to access.

Below is a sample code on how to do so [using python](https://github.com/Yancy-Godoy/GoogleWorkspace_DriveSDK/blob/main/listFilesFromAnotherUser.py) (but the idea is the same in every language):

```html
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import credentials, service_account

# Scopes required by this endpoint -> https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

# Service Account Credentials to be used. How to create at https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#service-account
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'YourServiceAccountCredentials.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes= SCOPES)
delegated_creds = credentials.with_subject("userToBeImpersonated@yourDomain.com")

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials = delegated_creds)

results = service.files().list(orderBy = 'name', pageSize = 100, corpora= 'user').execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

if not items:
    print("no files found")
else:
    print("Document name + FileID ")
    for item in items:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

#### Be advised:

- Domain Wide Delegation is required to access user's data in the Google Workspace environment as [documented here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106)
- You get the client ID from your GCP project by going to *APIs & Services > Credentials > Click on your Service Account > click on Advanced Settings* as shown below:

[image]

- Next you click on 'View Google Workspace Admin Console' and you need to go here:

[image]

- Click on 'Manage Domain Wide Delegation' > Add New > Add the client ID and the scopes required for the tasks you want to perform.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, Is there a way to do the same without enabling Domain wide delegation?

Comment: And what is the client ID here we are referring to?

Comment: @NehalBafna see my modified answer.

Comment: How to write above code in C#?